# Power supply physical design

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Why do they hermetically seal(No screws - need to cut to open it) power supplies for common household electronics like phones,routers.. etc?

Comment: Perhaps to avoid moisture damage

Comment: Ask yourself why not. Cost is the answer to most questions in engineering.

Comment: Pets and small children tend to pi$$ in corners where they are plugged in. Having said that one of my offspring came out from behind the settee looking very distressed and tight lipped. He was OK but he'd broken the lid off an amazon wall wart and shocked himself. He never said anything but the ease in which he'd managed to dislodge the wall-wart's plastic case surprised and appalled me in equal measures.

Answer (score 2):

Safety is a concern--moisture ingress can conduct dangerous AC voltages to the outside of the case.  There is probably also a slightly lower incidence of tampering when people know they can't easily reassemble the device.

The big driver, though, is cost.  Adding removable screws involves multiple operations per screw, whereas sonic welding is easily automated and doesn't increase the BOM in any way.  Assembly is thus easier, faster, and requires less parts.  This is the motivation for sonic welding in most cases.